# IntelliJ: Suddenly, existing import no longer works - cannot find declaration to go to

Tags: intellij-idea

The project has been working, and there's been no architectural changes whatsoever.

Suddenly, an import statement that was working is no longer working. The error message is

```
Cannot find a delcaration to go to
```

File: CaseSteps.java
Package: e2e.case

import e2e.caselist.CaseListSteps
 - This is the line getting the error

File: CaseListSteps
Package: e2e.caselist

If I start typing "import e2e.caselist." in the CaseSteps page, the autocomplete actually shows .CaseListSteps, and lets me select it. But it's marked with red for the "CaseListSteps" part, with the above error.

What on earth is this?

Comment: I occasionally also get this.  Have you recently changed your Maven settings?  Try doing an invalidate caches and restart, as this might resolve the problem.

Comment: Ah, fantastic. I love simple answers that work. Thanks :-)